# asp.net iis ask login for twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an asp.net application host on iis 10. When I login at the login page, sometimes I need to login twice. At first login, it will prompt

```
https://test.com/SZ/Default.aspx?source=https%3a%2f%2ftest.com%2fSZ%2ftasksearch.aspx
```

which is still the login page, then I login again, this time it really login and redirect to

```
https://test.com/SZ/tasksearch.aspx
```

sometimes I need to login three times, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I am not running web farm or web garden.

Comment: I copied the application directory from one server to another server, then problem exist.

Comment: So you are running the same app on two different web servers? Are you sure you aren't running a web farm?

Comment: They are not running web farms.

Comment: could you please provide sample code to reproduce the issue? which authentication you are using?